# Run Powershell Core from Powershell 5 remote pc

Tags: windows, powershell, server, powershell-core

I've installed Powershell Core on a remote PC.

I've entered into a remote session with Powershell 5 to that PC.

When i run

> PowerShell -NoExit "pwsh-preview"
>   or just pwsh-preview

it shows Powershell 7 intro and exits again to PS5 (see screenshot below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing how you are validating that this is happening.

All you are showing is the prompt return.

Start your session, then $PSVersionTable, then type pwsh, then type $PSVersionTable again.

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.628
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {...                                                                                 

pwsh

PowerShell 6.2.4
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS D:\Scripts> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.2.4
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    6.2.4
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.18363
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {...

PS D:\Scripts> exit

$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.628
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {...
```

You could easily change your profile to show you on your prompt what version you are in, as you switch between them.

As per your comment..
.

> there is no command like "pwsh" only pwsh-preview PSVersion
>   5.1.17763.771

Your statement is incorrect. that above screen output is the exact output from my system running the latest release of Powershell v7.

I am not new to this. I've been using PowerShell since before it was called PowerShell as an alpha user and insider.

> [Monad Manifesto – the Origin of Windows PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/monad-manifesto-the-origin-of-windows-powershell)

Here are the properties from the shortcut that gets created on installation.

> Shortcut title
>
> 'PowerShell 6 (x64)' ---
>
> shortcut path  "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.exe"
>   -WorkingDirectory ~

You are running an earlier preview and I am running current release. Hence the difference.

[image]

> https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases
>
> PowerShell-6.2.4-win-x64.msi
>
> PowerShell-6.2.4-win-x64.msix
>
> PowerShell-6.2.4-win-x64.zip
>
> PowerShell-6.2.4-win-x86.msi
>
> PowerShell-6.2.4-win-x86.zip

Comment: there is no command like "pwsh"
only pwsh-preview
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.771